# Angular2/4 How to automatically update formArray size according to inserted data?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following configuration for my form builder

```
 this.fb.group({
            id: [this.app.get('id'), []],
            tips: new FormArray([new FormControl('')]),
 })
```

I would like to update the size of tips, depending on the data that I am inserting into it during setValue() or patchValue(). If I have the following data

```
{
 id: 123,
 tips: [ 'Drink water', 'Exercise' ]
}
```

I would like the array to automatically expand. Does Angular have such a feature or do i have to check the size of the array and insert new controls into it ?

Comment: As a comment: What do you mean with *check the size of the array* mean? Why would you need to check the size? Maybe I'm stupid :)

Comment: lets say the size of the tips property that I am inserting into the array is 5 while the array is initialized as having just one form control; setValue() would throw an error; so one solution would be to update the size of the form array depending on the size of the data that I am pushing; but it would be nice if it could do that on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if I understood you correctly...

You want patch values you receive. An option would be to use `setControl()`, which replaces the existing `tips` FormArray.

```ts
myObject = {id: 123, tips: ['Drink water' , 'Exercise']}
```

And then do:

```ts
setValues() {
  this.myForm.setValue({
    id: this.obj.id,
  })
  // I like to inject 'FormBuilder' in constructor and use 'fb'
  this.myForm.setControl('tips', this.fb.array(this.obj.tips))
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this but this doesn't work in my case as I have validators in my array so, I guess I would have to simply loop through the array and insert the data

Comment: Yes, then I think you need to do that, at least I do not know of another way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where I did not want to lose my `Validators` or `valueChange` observable.

The simplest solution is to:

- Encapsulate your "tip" instantiation in a method to be reused
- Use `removeAt()` and `push()` to match the incoming value's length

```
    setFormValue(newValues: TipList): void {
        const tipArray: FormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('tips');

        // Remove controls in the list to match new value
        while (tipArray.length > newValues.tips.length) {
            tipArray.removeAt(0);
        }
        // Add controls in the list to match new value
        while (tipArray.length < newValues.tips.length) {
            tipArray.push(this.getNewTip());
        }

        // Finally set the incoming value
        this.myForm.setValue(newValues);
    }

    getNewTip(): FormControl {
        const tip: FormControl = new FormControl(''); // <- set validation here
        // Set other things like valueChange here
        return tip;
    }
```

You can see the working [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfqc15)